# shell command array output to csv columns using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

The following is output(log) of 'lastcomm' bash command.

```
python3                root     __         0.34 secs Tue Dec 11 09:06
python3                root     __         0.32 secs Tue Dec 11 09:06
python3                root     __         0.36 secs Tue Dec 11 09:06
cron             SF    root     __         0.00 secs Tue Dec 11 09:06
sh               S     root     __         0.00 secs Tue Dec 11 09:06
python3                root     __         0.29 secs Tue Dec 11 09:06
cron             SF    root     __         0.00 secs Tue Dec 11 09:06
sh               S     root     __         0.00 secs Tue Dec 11 09:06
python3                root     __         0.30 secs Tue Dec 11 09:06
cron             SF    root     __         0.00 secs Tue Dec 11 09:06
sh               S     root     __         0.00 secs Tue Dec 11 09:06
python3                root     __         0.31 secs Tue Dec 11 09:06
cron             SF    root     __         0.00 secs Tue Dec 11 09:06
sh               S     root     __         0.00 secs Tue Dec 11 09:06
python3                root     __         0.28 secs Tue Dec 11 09:06
sh                     root     __         0.00 secs Tue Dec 11 09:06
uname                  root     __         0.00 secs Tue Dec 11 09:06
```

I got a this by using the following code in python.

```
import subprocess
file_ = open("pacct.csv", "w")
subprocess.Popen(['lastcomm'], stdout=file_)
```

I'd like to separate the output(log) by columns and save csv file with columns structure.

But the above code only saves plain texts of entirely same output(log).
The delimiter(separators) of output is not 'tab' but 'different size of space', so it's really difficult to split list by columns.

How can I split the element of output(log) by columns and save csv file with columns structure using python3?

Desired Result :
(If I get a list structure such as the following, I will convert it to columns structure-csv file.)

```
[['python3', '', 'root', '_', '0.34 secs Tue Dec 11 09:06'],
['python3', '', 'root', '_', '0.32 secs Tue Dec 11 09:06'],
['python3', '', 'root', '_', '0.36 secs Tue Dec 11 09:06'],
['cron', 'SF', 'root', '_', '0.00 secs Tue Dec 11 09:06'],
['sh', 'S', 'root', '_', '0.00 secs Tue Dec 11 09:06'], ...]
```

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/lastcomm.1.html)

```
For each entry the following information is printed:
          + command name of the process
          + flags, as recorded by the system accounting routines:
               S -- command executed by super-user
               F -- command executed after a fork but without a following
       exec
               C -- command run in PDP-11 compatibility mode (VAX only)
               D -- command terminated with the generation of a core file
               X -- command was terminated with the signal SIGTERM
          + the name of the user who ran the process
          + time the process started
```

it's clear lastcomm provides `command`,`flags`,`user` and `time`

the `"__"` is just placeholder. You can get time by `row.split("__")[1].lstrip(" ").rstrip("\n")`

for `command`, search character from line beginning until first two space occur

and `user` do similar but reversed.

strip the rest of row contains with a space is `flags`